# Strange jquery 'viewport' behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

i'm developing a Wordpress site that has a lot of animations effects - fade-in and fade-out on changeing tabs etc. One of them i slideing in boxes from bottom when element is in viewport. I'm using this script:

```
function checkVisible() {
    var elm = this;
    var eval = eval || "visible";
    var vpH = $(window).height(),
        st = $(window).scrollTop(), 
        y = $(elm).offset().top,
        elementHeight = $(elm).height();

    if (eval == "visible") return ((y < (vpH + st)) && (y > (st - elementHeight)));

}



$(window).scroll(function(){ 
 $('.module').filter(checkVisible).addClass('come-in');
});

$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.module').filter(checkVisible).addClass('come-in'); 
});
```

It's not mine, i found it smowhere on Stackoverflow. 
The problem is, it worked for a while, but after some time it started to act strange:
On most subpages it just adds that 'come in' class without even checking if 'module' is in viewport or not. 
And on 'post' pages it works.. but when scrolling from bottom to top.

As i read a lot of problems may be caused by double jquery CDN, but i don't think thats the problem:

```
    <head>
<meta charset="utf-8" /> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<title>OsiemZero</title>
<script type="text/javascript">document.body.className+='animate-in'</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://serwer1460278.home.pl/osiemzero_wp/wp-content/themes/osiemzero/js/animations.js"></script>
<script src="http://serwer1460278.home.pl/osiemzero_wp/wp-content/themes/osiemzero/js/custom_css.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://serwer1460278.home.pl/osiemzero_wp/wp-content/plugins/ml-slider/assets/sliders/flexslider/jquery.flexslider-min.js?ver=3.3.6'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='metaslider-flex-slider-css'  href='http://serwer1460278.home.pl/osiemzero_wp/wp-content/plugins/ml-slider/assets/sliders/flexslider/flexslider.css?ver=3.3.6' type='text/css' media='all' property='stylesheet' />
<link rel="stylesheet" href=" http://serwer1460278.home.pl/osiemzero_wp/wp-content/themes/osiemzero/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://serwer1460278.home.pl/osiemzero_wp/wp-content/themes/osiemzero/css/styles.css">



</head>
```

I tried a lot of scripts that check if element is in viewport (even jquery plugins), but they had the same effect, so probably that's not the problem.

Thank you for any help possible.

Comment: why are you doing the same thing on both `scroll` as well as on `ready` ?

Comment: Becouse some of these elements are already on screen when the page loads. And some of them are below.

Comment: but all the sections are fully loaded(no matter their position on screen) when the your webpage loads?

Comment: Yes, but if i delete 'ready' line, animation starts on first scroll. Even when that element was visible earlier.

Comment: Please create a *Stack Snippet* or *JSFiddle* or something for better look into the issue.

Comment: I did, but the problem is it works without any issue on JSF fiddle.   https://jsfiddle.net/tvzp86jd/2/